# None Type Error Attribute

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I've been trying to implement a shopping cart on my website based on Django.

Below are the models I used:

```
class ShoppingCart(models.Model):
    songs = models.ManyToManyField(Song)
    albums = models.ManyToManyField(Album)

class Listener(User):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    cart = models.ForeignKey(ShoppingCart, blank=True, null=True)
```

Here is the `views.py` where I get an error saying `None Type Object has no attribute songs at request.user.listener.cart.songs.add()`:

```
def add_to_cart(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated() or not request.method == 'POST':
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'success':False}), content_type='application/json')
    typeobj = request.POST.get('type', None)
    obj = request.POST.get('id', None)
    if typeobj is None or obj is None:
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'success':False}), content_type='application/json')

    if typeobj == 'album':
        try:
            album = Album.objects.get(pk=obj)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'success':False}), content_type='application/json')
        request.user.listener.cart.albums.add(Album.objects.get(pk=obj))
    else:
        try:
            song = Song.objects.get(pk=obj)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'success':False}), content_type='application/json')
        request.user.listener.cart.songs.add(Song.objects.get(pk=obj))
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'success':True}), content_type='application/json')
```

I checked in the shell and the same error occurs when I try to add a song to the cart. It says cart is a `NoneType` object and has no attribute `songs`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I think you should use `OneToOne` relationship between `User` and `ShoppingCart`.

Sample model:

```
class Listener(User):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
   bio = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
   cart = models.OneToOneField(ShoppingCart, blank=True, null=True)
```

1. In your view create a `cart` for user if it does not exists

As

```
def add_to_cart(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated() or not request.method == 'POST':
       return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'success':False}), content_type='application/json')
    typeobj = request.POST.get('type', None)
    obj = request.POST.get('id', None)
    if typeobj is None or obj is None:
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'success':False}), content_type='application/json')

    if request.usr.listener.cart == None:
         cart = ShoppingCart()
         cart.save()
         request.usr.listener.cart = cart
         request.usr.listener.save()

    # your code to add items in cart
```

Comment: I got rid of the None Type Error. Thank you!
But now whats happening is that multiple cart are being created everytime I try to add a song to the cart. I opened the database and saw that no cart_id is being recorded in the listener table. Meaning there s no relation being setup between the listener and the cart.
Could this error be caused by a wrong implementation of .save() ?

Comment: @karthik, check the updated code, create `cart` object and save it and then assign and save in `listener`.

Comment: Thank you! For a further edit, request.usr.listener.save() works not request.usr.listener.cart.save() recreates the same error.

Comment: @karthik, Sorry last should be `request.usr.listener.save()` not `request.usr.listener.cart.save()`. Try with this.

Answer (score 1):

`request.user` is an instance of the `User` object of the currently logged in user.

There is no relation between your `Listener` model and the `User` model (even though you inherited from it), so whatever you are trying to do, it won't work.  In fact, even if there was a relationship, you'd be seeing these errors because you are not using the object relations correctly.

If you want to track a shopping cart for each user permanently, you need to add a `ForeignKey` to your `ShoppingCart` model to point to the `User` model.

If you just want to track the cart for a session; then use [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/) to do so.

It might benefit you from going through the [relations section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/relations/) of the documentation, since you aren't using `add()` correctly either.